# CentOS 9 and Alma 9 installers can't see my computer's hard drive

Tags: centos, system-installation, hard-disk

When I try to install 64-bit CentOS Stream 9 or Alma Linux 9 from either a USB stick or a DVD, the installation program lists all the hard drives on my system except the one to which I want to install CentOS or Alma. Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian installation programs have no such problem, they recognize the drive and would allow me to install there if I chose. Why don't CentOS or Alma recognize this hard drive? Here's the lshw output, run on Linux Mint:

```
 *-disk:1
      description: ATA Disk
      product: WDC WD4005FZBX-0
      vendor: Western Digital
      physical id: 0.1.0
      bus info: scsi@2:0.1.0
      logical name: /dev/sdb
      version: 1A01
      serial: VBGAH3JF
      size: 3726GiB (4TB)
      capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
      configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=84ed1367-c75d-4ab4-8009-036eb551c2db logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

If there's a fix for this, short of replacing the 4TB hard drive with another 4TB hard drive, what is it?

In response to a question about my post, yes, the disk is attached to the same SATA controller as the other disks.

Thanks!

Comment: is that disk attached through the same SATA controller as the other disks?

Comment: Yes, the disk is attached through the same SATA controller as the other disks.